# New Relic async tracing in Akka without Play

Tags: scala, akka, newrelic

I have application written using Akka library, and I want to use New Relic to monitor it. I've noticed that in case of Play applications, all async actions during request handling are [properly handled](http://blog-assets.newrelic.com/wp-content/uploads/TransactionTrace_Details.png), and all actors involved are shown in the web transaction trace.

But when I am trying to instrument pure Akka application using [custom java transaction traces](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-java-transaction-traces), I can't achieve the same result, all traces consist of just one line with `doJob` method name. Code below:

```
case class NewRelicRequest(...) extends Request { ... }
case class NewRelicResponse(...) extends Response { ... }


class MyApiActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case MyRequest(_) => doJob(...)
    case MyOtherRequest(_) => doOtherJob(...)
  }

  @Trace(dispatcher=true)
  private def doJob(...) {
    NewRelic.setRequestAndResponse(NewRelicRequest("/doJob"), NewRelicResponse(...))
    fooActor ! msg
  }

  @Trace(dispatcher=true)
  private def doOtherJob(...) {  
    NewRelic.setRequestAndResponse(NewRelicRequest("/doOtherJob"), NewRelicResponse(...))
    (barActor ? msg).pipeTo(sender)
  }

}
```

Can someone explain what cases are supported, and how can I achieve async traces similar to those I see for Play apps?

Comment: New Relic monitors Akka 2.0 - 2.1 async tracking for Play applications.  It does not currently support Akka stand alone applications.  If you are looking to get this working you may want to open a support ticket up with New Relic at support.newrelic.com and they can look into this further.